# Applying lots of shape keys with blends using Python not working? also, is there another way?

Tags: python, scripting, export, shape-keys, .fbx

I'm trying to make a script so that I can apply all blended shape keys (starting from a specific one and then iterating through the list, keeping them in order) so that they work well when exporting as fbx but it's making a bit of a mess for some reason and I can't figure out why. Anyone has an idea? Or is there any other way to apply lots of shape keys with blends in an efficient way?

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.object
shapekeysList = len(obj.data.shape_keys.key_blocks)
spIndex = obj.active_shape_key_index

for sp in obj.data.shape_keys.key_blocks:
    print (obj.active_shape_key.name)
    obj.active_shape_key.value = 1   # enable shapekey before copying

    #apply shapekey
    obj.shape_key_add(name=str(obj.active_shape_key.name) + "_applied", from_mix=True)

    obj.active_shape_key.value = 0              # reset shapekey
    obj.active_shape_key_index = spIndex        # select shapekey
    bpy.ops.object.shape_key_remove()           # delete blended shape key

    # select next shape key
    spIndex = spIndex + 1
    obj.active_shape_key_index = spIndex
```

These are the original shape keys:

[image: original]

These are the original shape keys left after running the script:

[image: original_created]

These are the ones that get created:

[image: created]

This is my first Python script for Blender so I might be missing something pretty obvious or something...
Thanks!

UPDATE: Ok if I go one by one manually with this code it works... but if I try to loop it it messes everything up, so the looping part is the one that's not working o.O

```
print (obj.active_shape_key.name)
obj.active_shape_key.value = 1              # enable shapekey before copying
index = obj.active_shape_key_index          # save index
obj.shape_key_add(name=str(obj.active_shape_key.name) + "_applied", from_mix=True)   #apply shapekey
obj.active_shape_key_index = index          # select original selection
bpy.ops.object.shape_key_remove()           # delete blended shape key
obj.active_shape_key_index += 1             # selec next in list
```

Also tried looping with this:

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.object
shapekeysList = len(obj.data.shape_keys.key_blocks)
spIndex = obj.active_shape_key_index

shapekeysList = []
for sp in obj.data.shape_keys.key_blocks:
    shapekeysList.append(sp)

for sp in shapekeysList:
    #the thing that's in the snipet above
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got this working:

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.object
spIndex = obj.active_shape_key_index
i = 0

### EDITABLE VARIABLES ###
last = "fullbody"       # Last shapekey to save
add =  "_applied"       # Add this to new blendshape's name

shapekeysList = []
shapekeyValues = []

for sp in obj.data.shape_keys.key_blocks:
    if last in sp.name:
        break
    shapekeysList.append(sp)
    shapekeyValues.append(sp.value)
    sp.value = 0
    print (shapekeysList[i].name + " | Value saved: " +  str(shapekeyValues[i]))
    i += 1

print ('\nFinished saving shape keys\n')
i = spIndex

while i < len(shapekeysList):
    shapekeysList[i].value = 1                                  # enable shapekey before copying
    print (shapekeysList[i].name + " | " + str(shapekeysList[i].value))

    obj.active_shape_key_index = i                    # select shape key to mix

    obj.shape_key_add(name=str(obj.active_shape_key.name) + add, from_mix=True)   #apply shapekey
    obj.active_shape_key_index = i                    # select original selection
    #bpy.ops.object.shape_key_remove()                           # delete blended shape key
    shapekeysList[i].value = 0
    #obj.active_shape_key_index += 1                             # select next in list
    i += 1
```